# Escaping double quotes in a Fuseki SPARQL query?

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, semantic-web, fuseki

Is it possible to use double quotes as part of a URI in a SPARQL query using Fuseki? I'm working off of a DBpedia dataset and it has some URIs like:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/"Crocodile"_Dundee>
```

I've tried:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> SELECT ?summary WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/\"Crocodile\"_Dundee> dbo:abstract ?summary }" localhost:3030/knowledge/query

PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> SELECT ?summary WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/%22Crocodile%22_Dundee> dbo:abstract ?summary }" localhost:3030/knowledge/query
```

but continue to get the following error:

```
Encountered " "<" "< "" at line 1, column 68.
Was expecting one of:
<IRIref> ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more reading and experimentation, the issue was because I was not properly setting the `Content-Type` header. It needs to be set to `application/sparql-query`, and then you can use percent-encoding (though it is discouraged by the SPARQL spec), like so:

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> SELECT ?summary WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/%22Crocodile%22_Dundee> dbo:abstract ?summary }' localhost:3030/knowledge/query  --header "Content-Type: application/sparql-query"
```

Unfortunately I still could not get escaped double quotes to work.

As a bonus, this also lets you use ampersands (&) in queries:

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> SELECT ?uri WHERE { { ?alias_uri rdfs:label "Gibson Dunn & Crutcher"@en; dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?uri . } UNION { ?uri rdfs:label "Gibson Dunn & Crutcher"@en NOT EXISTS {  ?uri dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?nil } } } ' localhost:3030/knowledge/query --header "Content-Type: application/sparql-query"
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here:

1. Double quotes are not allowed in URIs (RFC 3986).
2. When you send %22 as a query string in a HTTP URL, the other end will decode that and get "

hence using POST and putting the query in the body avoids the problems (or encode the % itself getting send %2522).

Using `--data-binary` not `-d` is safer yet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I was assuming the issue was that double quotes makes it an invalid IRI, but unfortunately DBpedia doesn't go by that convention.

Comment: @frnsys Can you provide any clarification about what you mean by "DBpedia doesn't go by that convention"?  DBpedia doesn't define what makes an IRI valid or invalid, after all.  It's possible that they have malformed data, but in that case, can you provide an example? The [Encoding scheme of DBpedia URIs](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/URIencoding?v=9oh) says “The following characters that may occur in Wikipedia page names are percent-encoded: " (double quotes) % (percent)
? (question mark)
\ (backslash)
^ (caret)
` (backtick)”.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I was getting URIs like `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/"Crocodile"_Dundee>` rather than with their percent encoding, but I'm realizing now it is probably because they were already decoded by the time I received them.